# how to resolve runtime error in mvc3 razor view (Assembly 'MvcApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a mvc3 web razor application in visual studio 2010 professional. I added mvc3 web project with razor view but when i compile it it gives error of MVC.WEB.dll older version. then i updated mvc.web.dll to version 4 and web.mvc.webpages to version 2 in my refference assemblieis.

I already added the web.config file configurations when it gives compile time error as show below

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

but now it not give the compile time error as shown below.

```
Assembly 'MvcApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Please help me to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 1):

`I want to create a mvc3 web razor application`

and then

`i updated mvc.web.dll to version 4`

what?

Exception `... which has a higher version than referenced assembly ...`

Try to remove reference from project references (left click on `System.Web.Mvc` and press delete), then `References -> Add reference` sort by name on first tab and select `System.Web.Mvc` with 4.0.0.0 in second column (version).

Comment: I already do this but the error is still come at runtime plz give me some other suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: @churahi Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402005/aspnet-compiler-finding-wrong-version-of-system-web-webpages-1-0-0-0-instead-of  Where is `<system.web>` section?

Answer (score 0):

Under the References you will find the `System.Web.Mvc` referenced

[image]

remove this reference and add a new reference of higher version i.e `4.x`

[image]

Comment: I did the same which you said but the same error is come at runtime. Plz help me what i do for resolve this error.