# ASP.NET Compiler complaining of mismatching framework versions with MiniProfiler

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, binding, mvc-mini-profiler

I have an MVC3 project that I upgraded from VS2010 to VS2012. The project also has a reference to `MiniProfiler`. Our application compiles and runs fine in VS2012 without any warnings/errors. Both assemblies load fine when running with IIS Express. When using the ASP.NET Compiler tool, however, I get the following warning:

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET Compilation Tool version 4.0.30319.17929 Utility
>   to precompile an ASP.NET application Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> (0): warning : The following assembly has dependencies on a version of
>   the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load
>   correctly during runtime causing a failure: MiniProfiler,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3. The
>   dependencies are: System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. You should either ensure that the
>   dependent assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that
>   the target framework you are addressing is that of the dependent
>   assembly.

We don't have an explicit reference to `System.Data.Linq`. Up until the update to VS2012, we didn't have any errors. The `MiniProfiler` version is indeed targeting .NET 4.0 (as is our application). What could be causing this warning?

Comment: I've had a look at the setups, and I can't see anything obviously wrong that might cause this...

Comment: @MarcGravell - So what's really weird is that if I create a new project and use the same approach above, it'll work just fine... :(

Comment: Could check the bin directories for any funky dll's that could have ended up there? Also backup your obj folder then delete it from the project I find that helps with all kinds of oddities ;o)

Comment: @bUKaneer - It wouldn't be the obj folder since we run the `aspnet_compiler` outside of that directory structure. I also checked the pre-compiled bin folder and can't find anything odd.. :(

Comment: I seem to be having this same problem with a different pre-compiled project.  All the assemblies are on .Net 4, but it complains about a mismatch of versions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was finally able to fix it with a tip from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10431075/200322). I added the following `<add>` line in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <!-- etc... -->
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <!-- etc... -->
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  <system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you changed targetFramework inside Web.confing?