# WebGrease warning when building a deployment package

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, publishing, webdeploy

Getting the following warning from aspnet_compiler.exe when building a deployment package:

```
ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Warning : The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a failure: WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. The dependencies are: System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. You should either ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is that of the dependent assembly.
```

Same thing happened before I updated WebGrease from version 1.3.0.0
Tried both of the following assembly bindings without success:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I spent 2 days on this already frying different configurations and would greatly appreciate any hint or help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message, the problem is in the .Net framework you are targeting. Right click on the project, choose properties, and change the .Net target framework to 4.5.1.  I had the same problem after moving from visual studio 2012 to 2013 and that fixed it for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

I solved this issue by adding a reference on **System.Windows.Forms** with the following configuration in `web.config` :

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Inspired by [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18192796/164150).