# Errors and warnings seemingly related to application pool issues in IIS after framework upgrade

Tags: c#, iis

Some unexpected warnings and errors started appearing in my Soap Service after I had updated from .Net Framework 4.0 to 4.5.2 on Windows 7.

The errors all disappeared after I removed an old framework 2 application pool from IIS. I also removed all old application pools so that I only had 1 application pool for my project.

After this I was unable to reproduce the error by adding back a framework 2 application pool.

The issues I experienced and subsequently resolved where

[Issue 1: Warning]

**The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET
    Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during
    runtime causing a failure**

The complete error was

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET
Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during
runtime causing a failure: SBD.Common, Version=2.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=a3471ea16b9add4c. The dependencies are: mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; System, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; 
System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; System.Xml, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; 
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. You should either ensure that the dependent 
assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that the target 
framework you are addressing is that of the dependent assembly.
```

**

[Issue 2 Error]

**CS1502    The best overloaded method match for ( mymethod ) has some invalid arguements**

In the code

```
[SoapHeader("CoreHeader")]
public bool QueueDeleteDesigns(int itemId, int[] designIDs)
{
   CheckCoreHeader();
   string s = string.Join(",", designIDs);
   // etc
```

Intellisense also showed

```
The type 'IQueryable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You 
must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version =4.0.0.0
```

**

[Issue 3 Warning]

**warning CS1684: Reference to type 'System.Tuple`2' claims it is defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll', but it could not be found**

Comment: And what version is *your* project set to?

Comment: @kirsteng BenVoight asked the target of *your* project, not the DLL's.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971340/asp-net-compiler-complaining-of-mismatching-framework-versions-with-miniprofiler?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably won't need this step but just for completeness:
   Check your **applicationhost.config** file - if you manually added an entry to it, make sure it reads this for your site:

   `<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">`
2. This would most probably fix the issue: 
   In your **web.config** file, make sure your compilation tag has the framework version and a valid temporary directory path which is accessible by your IIS_IUSRS or IIS_WPG usergroups (read more about user groups here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis):

   `<compilation debug="True" strict="False" explicit="True" targetFramework="4.0" tempDirectory="C:\inetpub\temp\">`

Comment: Just try the second then.

Comment: When you build every project separately, in which project(s) do you get this error?

Comment: Two things you can check:

1. In Start->Run->inetmgr:
Is your website mapped to correct AppPool?

2. Are there references to 3rd party dll files in your SBD.Common and web projects, which require .net runtime 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole day troubleshooting these 3 issues , and I am unclear as to what the exact fix was, because after fixing the issues I was unable to reproduce them.

I think it was to do with cleaning up old application pools in IIS.