# Orchard.Framework error with Reference

Tags: reference, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Following the orchard tutorials - http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-7

Error is occuring when I paste the 4th black screen shot from the above link into my project (see code below)

```
 using Orchard.UI.Resources;

namespace Skywalker.Webshop
{
    public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider
    {
        public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
        {
            // Create and add a new manifest
            var manifest = builder.Add();

            // Define a "common" style sheet
            manifest.DefineStyle("Skywalker.Webshop.Common").SetUrl("common.css");

            // Define the "shoppingcart" style sheet
            manifest.DefineStyle("Skywalker.Webshop.ShoppingCart").SetUrl("shoppingcart.css").SetDependencies("Skywalker.Webshop.Common");
        }
    }
}
```

Assembly 'Orchard.Framework, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version =2.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than references assembly 'system.webPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?
Thanks for any replies

**EDIT**
The error is coming from referencing the style sheet:
manifest.DefineStyle("Skywalker1.Webshop.Common").SetUrl("common.css");

manifest.DefineStyle("Skywalker1.Webshop.ShoppingCart").SetUrl("shoppingcart.css").SetDependencies("Skywalker1.Webshop.Common");*

but i can't resolve it...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added a reference to System.webPages to your own project, pointing at an older version than Orchard is using. Check your module projects references section, and ensure that the versions match up.

You should also check this quite detailed post on the issue. [aspnet_compiler finding wrong version of System.Web.WebPages 1.0.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402005/aspnet-compiler-finding-wrong-version-of-system-web-webpages-1-0-0-0-instead-of)