# aspnet_compiler.exe not finding dependentAssembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, precompile

We have an ASP.NET application that works fine when built and deployed with VS 2019. However, when I enable the *Precompile* mode, it has a problem finding a dependent assembly.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_compiler.exe -v \ -p C:\git\repo.xyz\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -c C:\git\repo.xyz\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir

C:\git\repo.xyz\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET Compilation Tool version 4.8.4084.0
Utility to precompile an ASP.NET application
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error ASPRUNTIME: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I found this similar question, but none of those answers worked for me:

[aspnet_compiler finding wrong version of System.Web.WebPages 1.0.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402005/aspnet-compiler-finding-wrong-version-of-system-web-webpages-1-0-0-0-instead-of)

We use nuget across the board for package configuration. We have chosen to use System.Web.Mvc 5.2.7, and have this configured in the project web.config:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.8.0">
  <assemblies>
    ..
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

NOTE: I have also tried `Version=5.2.0.0`.

Some packages have dependency references for earlier versions, so we have a dependentAssembly to cover those cases:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

This works for a standard Build and Publish from VS. I just can't figure out why aspnet_compiler.exe is not reading/respecting the web.config in the project root (C:\git\repo.xyz\MyProject\web.config).